# Box-Cox parameter confidence interval clarification

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, data-transformation, boxcox-transformation

In their [original publication](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984418), Box and Cox state

> ...we can obtain an approximate $100(1 - \alpha)$ per cent confidence region [around $\hat{\lambda}$] from
> $$
> L_\text{max} (\hat{\lambda}) - L_\text{max}(\lambda) < \frac{1}{2}\chi^2_{\nu_\lambda}(\alpha)\ ,
> $$
> where $\nu_\lambda$ is the number of independent components in $\lambda$.

They unfortunately do not explain their notation: does $\chi^2(\cdot)$ refer to the CDF, the PDF or something else? Further, what exactly is $\nu_\lambda$? Concretely, if I am applying a Box-Cox transform to a time series of length $N$, is $\nu_\lambda= N-1$, for instance?

For reference, the `scipy` Python package lists [the following formula](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) for the confidence interval of their Box-Cox implementation:
$$
L_\text{max} (\hat{\lambda}) - L_\text{max}(\lambda) < \frac{1}{2}\chi^2(1 - \alpha, 1)\ ;
$$
digging into [the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c1ed5ece8ffbf05356a22a8106affcd11bd3aee0/scipy/stats/_morestats.py#L938), it appears that the compute the PPF of $1- \alpha$, and always assume $1$ df for the $\chi^2$; is this correct?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This is standard shorthand. The context implies they refer to an appropriate *quantile* of the chi-squared distribution. Reviewing the theory of hypothesis testing, the [meaning of p values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31), the [Neyman-Pearson lemma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Neyman+pearson+lemma), and the [Likelihood Ratio test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=likelihood+ratio+test) can be helpful. They will show you that $\nu_\lambda$ is not the size of your dataset, but rather it's the number of *separate parameters* used in estimating $\lambda.$

Comment: Thanks for this. I would accept this as an answer if you care to post it as such.